# Does Google ever see my code?

Tags: seo, google-crawlers

I have been looking a lot online and I have always thought that Google's spiders saw the code, but after research it seems as if this isn't true. I am knew to seo and haven't had much experience yet. I especially wanted to know if Google could see include files in PHP and it seems that this is true. I just haven't been able to find an answer to whether Google actually sees my code.
Any help would be great.

Comment: I didn't search include/require files specifically, but that is good to know. So it looks as if they don't ever see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a `Server Side Scripting Language` which is responsible for rendering an HTML output.

A bot acts exactly like a browser client, and will only see the rendered HTML output of any scripts.

No, your PHP code is never seen by a bot, or any client.

Answer (score 0):

Search Engine Crawlers do not access your server side code (PHP). It only has access to the markup that is on the page. Here the markup includes Javascript, CSS and generated HTML using PHP.